# C++/OpenGL Random Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl

So I'm writing a chunk based procedurally generated terrain game and am running into two errors:

Basically, the way it's working is it generates chunks around the player position, once per game loop.

```
for (int i = RENDER_RADIUS; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = RENDER_RADIUS; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            terr.renderChunk(glm::ivec2(c->getXOff() + i, c->getZOff() + j), cubeShader);
            terr.renderChunk(glm::ivec2(c->getXOff() - i, c->getZOff() - j), cubeShader);
            terr.renderChunk(glm::ivec2(c->getXOff() - i, c->getZOff() + j), cubeShader);
            terr.renderChunk(glm::ivec2(c->getXOff() + i, c->getZOff() - j), cubeShader);
        }
    }
```

In terr.renderChunk I am using a unordered_map that uses the chunks position as the key and the chunk is the value. If the unordered_map doesn't find the chunk then the position gets added to terr.updateList.

Then, back in the game loop:

```
if (!terr.updateList.empty())
    {
        terr.updateChunk(terr.updateList[terr.updateList.size()-1]);
        terr.world[terr.updateList[terr.updateList.size()-1]]->render(cubeShader);
        terr.updateList.pop_back();
    }
```

In a separate line, I'm ensuring that the players current chunk is loaded as well.

To generate a chunks VBO I added the indices to the chunks vector points and then build it as so:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->VAO);
glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);

// vertice VBO
glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO_VERT);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO_VERT);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->points.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &this->points[0][0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

// texture coords
glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO_UV);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO_UV);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->uvs.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &this->uvs[0][0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Now, it all generally works, but I randomly get a segmentation fault and have debugged it down to my render function:

```
void Chunk::render(Shader shader)
{
    shader.setMat4("transform", offsetMatrix);
    shader.setFloat("transparency", 1.0f);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    cout << "size " << points.size() << endl;
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, points.size()); //RIGHT HERE CAUSES THE SEGFAULTS
    cout << "TEST2" << endl;
}
```

The segmentation fault seems to happen randomly, however, I do believe it doesn't happen on new chunks but rather going back over old ones.

My question was, is there anything specific with OpenGL/C++ that I'm unaware of that could be causing it?

The other error I'm getting that may be related but I've debugged less is I'm getting chunk rendering errors [as so](https://ibb.co/f5P18K) where it renders random terrain but when I go into it, collision still works as if terrain was where it should be.

I realize this is a long question, but any support is really appreciated!

Comment: 1. you are probably accessing uninitialized memory somewhere; 2. don't use "endl" -- it can be expensive as it flushes buffers, use "\n".

Comment: I'm just using "endl" for debugging purposes.

Comment: can you use a debugger to examine what is going on at the time of failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching your render call to a renderChunk looks like it would be a safer alternative, not sure if it'd fix the segfault but from what I can see, that's a safer, and not too much slower bet.